# how to modify/add/delete tool installations on a Jenkins slave using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

atm I am using a Groovy script to configure our different Jenkins masters, including the tool installations, eg:

```
mavenDesc = Jenkins.instance.getDescriptorByName("hudson.tasks.Maven");
if (mavenDesc != null) {
  MavenInstallation mi = new MavenInstallation("maven3.0.2", "/home/jenkins/apache-maven-3.0.2");
  MavenInstallation mi32 = new MavenInstallation("maven3.2.3", "/home/jenkins/apache-maven-3.2.3");
  mavenDesc.setInstallations(mi, mi32);
}
```

This works fine but now I want to do the same for the slaves (different OS so different locations). Can't figure out how though...this is the furthest I have gotten:

```
for (aSlave in jenkins.slaves) {
  for ( ToolLocationNodeProperty.ToolLocation toolLocation : aSlave.getNodeProperties().get(ToolLocationNodeProperty.class).getLocations()) {
    //println(toolLocation.getKey())    
    //println(toolLocation.getType())
    println(toolLocation.getName())
    println(toolLocation.getHome())
  }
}
```

All instances seem immutable though and I don't seem to find any way to add a Tool location to a slave.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodeProperties.replace(toolLocation)` should do the job.